# How is Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm for quantum computation useful?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer

In [Deutsch–Jozsa algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsch%E2%80%93Jozsa_algorithm), in order to encode the function into a unitary which can be used for the computation, we need to know the function beforehand. What is the use of finding whether a function is balanced or not if we already know what the function does?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to know the function beforehand, just some properties of it.

The idea is that you are assuming to know *something* about the function (it is either balanced or unbalanced), but lack some additional amount of information to completely characterise it.
Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm shows that this additional amount of information, under some circumstances, can be efficiently recovered.